# useQuery returns stale data on rendering for first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using a useQuery which is of the form:
const { data } = useQuery(foo, async () => {...})

where

foo is a value that changes when I perform an action, say, select a dropdown menu item, item1
when I do that, useQuery is called with the stale data
The entire functional component is re-rendered, going to the initial value
When I click on item1 in the dropdown again, the component is rendered with the correct value
I use staleTime: Infinity

I want the component to render the proper value immediately and not on multiple reload of component. Please let me know if using useQuery in this case would be a good idea

`const ids: number[] = useMemo(() => { return sampleArray.map((sampleOption) => Number(sampleOption.Team.Id)); }, [sampleArray]);`

Here sampleArray value is determined by change in dropdown value

`const { data: information} = useQuery(["key", ids], () => getInfo(ids), { staleTime: Infinity, enabled: !!param1 });`

Comment: i think that you dont need to specify "async" in that callback, can this be your issue?

Comment: What are the config values? `staleTime`, `cacheTime`, `keepPreviousData` and so on?

Comment: Please post more of your code so we can help you debug the issue

Comment: `const ids: number[] = useMemo(() => {
return sampleArray.map((sampleOption) => Number(sampleOption.Team.Id));
}, [sampleArray]);

const { data: information} = useQuery(["key", ids], () => getInfo(ids), {
staleTime: Infinity,
enabled: !!param1
});`

Comment: this would be the sample code

Comment: param1 is fixed